# Cache busting in gulp only working with index.html changes, not css or js changes

Tags: caching, npm, gulp

I'm having issues with the browsers cache so I am trying to update the index.html file if the css, js or html files are changed.

The line I want to update is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css?cb=123" />
```

more importantly the **?cb=123** part

Basically my gulp function looks for 'cb=' and updates it with a new number based on the date and time.

This index.html updates fine if i use the following gulpfile.js. Any changes to the index.html file results in a new **cb** number.

```
// --------------------------------------------
// Gulp Loader
// --------------------------------------------

const {
    src,
    dest,
    task,
    watch,
    series,
    parallel
  } = require("gulp");

  // --------------------------------------------
  // Dependencies
  // --------------------------------------------

  const homedir = require("os").homedir();
  var path = require("path");
  var pathDir = require("path").resolve(__dirname, "../../");
  var parentDir = path
    .dirname(pathDir)
    .split(path.sep)
    .pop();

  var newParent = parentDir.split(" ").join("_");

  var parentdir = path.basename(path.dirname(pathDir));
  parentdir = parentDir.replace(/[^\w]/g, "");
  parentdir = parentDir.replace(/[^\w]/g, "").toLowerCase();

  // HTML plugins
  let htmlmin = require("gulp-htmlmin");

  // CSS / SASS plugins
  let sass = require("gulp-sass");
  let autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
  let minifycss = require("gulp-clean-css");
  let postcss = require("gulp-postcss");
  let cssnano = require("cssnano");

  // JSS / plugins
  let uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

  // Utility plugins
  let concat = require("gulp-concat");
  let del = require("del");
  let plumber = require("gulp-plumber");
  let sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
  let rename = require("gulp-rename");
  let fileinclude = require("gulp-file-include");
  var replace = require('gulp-replace');

  // Browser plugins
  let browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

  // Images plugins
  let imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");
  let embedSvg = require("gulp-embed-svg");

  // --------------------------------------------
  // Project Variables
  // --------------------------------------------

  let htmlSrc = "source/";
  let htmlDest = homedir + "/sites/blog/";

  let incSrc = "source/includes/";

  let styleSrc = "source/styles/";
  let styleDest = homedir + "/sites/blog/styles/";

  let vendorSrc = "source/scripts/vendors/";
  let scriptSrc = "source/scripts/";
  let scriptDest = homedir + "/sites/blog/scripts/";

  let imageSrc = "source/images/";
  let imageDest = homedir + "/sites/blog/images/";

  let fontSrc = "source/fonts/";
  let fontDest = homedir + "/sites/blog/fonts/";

  // --------------------------------------------
  // Tasks
  // --------------------------------------------

  // CSS
  function css(done) {
    src([
      styleSrc + 'main.scss',
    ])

      .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'compressed'
      }))
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(dest(styleDest));
    done();
  };

  // JS
  function js(done) {
    src([scriptSrc + "*.js", vendorSrc + "*.js"])
      .pipe(
        rename({
          basename: "main",
          suffix: ".min"
        })
      )
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(dest(scriptDest));
    done();
  }

  // HTML
  function html(done) {
    var cbString = new Date().getTime();
    src(htmlSrc + "index.html")
      .pipe(
        fileinclude({
          prefix: "@@",
          basepath: "source/includes"
        })
      )
      .pipe(replace(/cb=\d+/, 'cb=' + cbString))
      .pipe(
        embedSvg({
          root: "./source/images/",
          selectors: ".inline-svg"
        })
      )
      .pipe(
        htmlmin({
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          minifyCSS: true,
          minifyJS: {
            compress: {
              drop_console: true
            }
          },
          processConditionalComments: true,
          removeComments: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
          removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
          processScripts: ["application/ld+json"]
        })
      )
      .pipe(dest(htmlDest));
    done();
  }

  // IMAGES
  function img(done) {
    src(imageSrc + "*")
      .pipe(imagemin())
      .pipe(dest(imageDest));
    done();
  }

  // FONTS
  function fonts(done) {
    src(fontSrc + "*").pipe(dest(fontDest));
    done();
  }

  // --------------------------------------------
  // Watch for changes
  // --------------------------------------------

  function watcher() {
    // Serve files from the root of this project
    browserSync.init({
      server: {
        baseDir: homedir + "/sites/blog/",
      },
      notify: false
    });

    watch(htmlSrc, series(html)).on("change", browserSync.reload);
    watch(styleSrc, series(css)).on("change", browserSync.reload);
    watch(scriptSrc, series(js)).on("change", browserSync.reload);
    watch(imageSrc, series(img)).on("change", browserSync.reload);
    watch(imageSrc, series(fonts)).on("change", browserSync.reload);
  }

  // use default task to launch Browsersync and watch JS files
  var build = parallel(css, js, html, img, fonts, watcher);
  task("default", build);
```

But the number only updates if the index.html file is changed so back to the drawing board..

Now as I want the number to update if I update the js or css files, I have tried taking the following line out of the html function and giving it it's function:

```
.pipe(replace(/cb=\d+/, 'cb=' + cbString))
```

Like so:

```
// Cachebust
function cacheBustTask(done) {
  var cbString = new Date().getTime();
  src(htmlSrc + "index.html")
    .pipe(replace(/cb=\d+/g, 'cb=' + cbString))
    .pipe(dest(htmlDest));
  done();
}
```

But this brakes the site.

Any idears how I can get the task **cacheBustTask** to work along side the **html** task.

Here's the full updated gulpfile.js with the separate **cacheBustTask** task/function

Answer (score 1):

Say you have this folder structure:

```
src
  js
    index.js
  scss
    index.scss
public
about.html     << target this one
index.html     << target this one
```

and you want to add cachebusting **only to `.js` and `.css` files**:

to convert say:

```html
<script src="dist/index.js?cb=0"></script>
```

into:

```html
<script src="dist/index.js?cb=1607437629110"></script>
```

use this inside your **gulpfile.js**

```js
function cacheBustTask(){
    return src(['index.html', 'about.html'])
        .pipe(replace(/(\.(css|js)\?cb=)\d+\b/g, `$1${Date.now()}`))
        .pipe(dest('.'));
}
```

If you want to target **all `.html` files**  use a wildcard `**`

```
return src(["**/*.html"])
```

#### Additional notes:

Since every time you make some changes your pipeline triggers this modifications you might run into the issue or pushing to Git files that you actually did not touched.
Therefore you should add to your pipeline to run the above only when building for **production**.

So basically in development mode (inside your `src` folder) you should always see the suffix `?cb=0` - and only the timestamp suffixed ones `?cb=1607437629110` inside the files that end up inside `dist` - only once you build your project for production.

Comment: This doesn't work (for me anyways). I'm in a very similar situation but my issue is that the js and css files have cb=####### whatever numbers but in my html, the ###### don't match. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: @e11world where are your `.html` files situated? If you look at the above example - the specific code would work if your `.html` files are inside root folder. Also, you should  initially have a number (any number defined i.e: `<script src="dist/functions.js?cb=0"></script>`)

Comment: @e11world perhaps you could use a wildcard like i.e: `["**/*.html"]` to target *any* `.html` file

Comment: I don't think I applied the default number to my links so that could be it. I did try the wildcard thing but I'm limiting it to certain dir (src/**/*.html).

Comment: @e11world I frankly don't understand your comment, it's a suggestion or a question?

Comment: It's a comment only. I will check things again as I left it without implementing that part. Will ask again soon.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your own cache-busting system there are some plugins that do this.  I use
[gulp-version-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-version-number).

```js
const addVersionString = require("gulp-version-number");


const versionConfig = {
  "value": "%DT%",
  "append": {
    "key": "v",
    "to": ["css", "js"],
  },
};

function processHTML() {
  return gulp.src(paths.html.src)
    .pipe(print())

    // modifyHTMLlinks: remove browserSync script link
    // update css/js links to .min.css or .min.js
    .pipe(modifyHTMLlinks())

    .pipe(stripComments.html(stripOptions))

    // add ?v=dateTime stamp to css and js links
    .pipe(addVersionString(versionConfig))

    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.html.deploy));
}
```

and you'll end with

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.min.css?v=20201206182221">
  <script src="js/app.min.js?v=20201206182221"></script>
```

I don't use it for the `html` file as well, so you'll have to modify the configuration to add that.